# Every complex manifold is almost complex

Tags: complex-manifolds, almost-complex

Recall that $M$ is a complex manifold if $M$ is a topological manifold and there is an atlas $\{ \varphi_i : U_i \to \mathbb C^n\}$ such that the transition functions $\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1}$ are holomorphic.

Why is that every complex manifold is almost complex? That is, how to construct the $(1,1)$ tensor $J$ so that $J^{2}=-id$?

Comment: Mulitplication by $\sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is a complex manifold, let $(z_1,...,z_n)$ be a local complex coordinates at the point $p$ of  $M$. If $z_i=x_i+\sqrt{-1}y_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$, then as a smooth manifold, $M$ has local coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n)$ and the tangent space at $p$ is spanned by 
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$ for $i=1,2,...,n.$
Define $J:T_pM\to T_pM$ by 
$$J(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\mbox{ and }
J(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\mbox{ for all }i=1,2,...,n.$$
Then $J^2=-id$ which shows that $J$ is an almost complex structure.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this answer is to point out that the almost complex structure constructed in the [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1046453/629362) is well-defined, independent of the complex coordinates chosen.

If $(u_1, \cdots, u_n, v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ is another local complex coordinates of $M$ which intersects with the $(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_n)$ coordinates. Assume that $\tilde J$ is constructed so that

$$ \tilde J \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}\right) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial v_i}, \ \ \ \tilde J \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial v_i}\right) =-  \frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}$$

then by the first Cauchy Riemann equation $\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial y_i}$,

\begin{align}
\tilde J \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right) &= \tilde J \left( \sum_j \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial u_j}\right) \\
&=\sum_j \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \tilde J \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial u_j}\right) \\
&=\sum_j \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial y_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial v_j} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}.
\end{align}

and similarly $\tilde J \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}\right) =- \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$. Thus $\tilde J=J$ and so $J$ is well-defined.